# Running script automatically in vagrant

Tags: provisioning, vagrant

How can I run a script automatically when vagrant is up? I used provision method. But in that method i need to point out some `.sh` file. I dont want to point to `.sh` file. I need to build the script within the `Vagrantfile`. Please help me to fix this issue.

I tried

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "test.sh
end
```

I want to append the scripts in `test.sh` into vagrant file directly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use inline script in `Vagrantfile`, even Here Document which made complex shell scripts embedded in it possible.

Example:

```
$script = <<'EOF'
echo shell provisioning...
date -R > /etc/vagrant_provisioned_at
EOF

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => $script
end
```

NOTE: single quoted LimitString is to escape special characters like `or`$`.

Check the Docs out => http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html

Comment: Yes, <<EOF is a [here documents](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html), you can put your scripts in between <<EOF and `EOF`. Single quote EOF (limitString) to escape special characters.